# External HDD error

Tags: mount, hard-drive, windows-10, external-hdd

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNwsm.jpg

Hello so I decided to fully convert to Linux since windows made me sometimes mad and was a little restrictive, anyways, I downloaded an ISO with ubuntu and decided to delete all the HDD since I wanted to start cleanly, I backed all my data in my external HDD disk which had cache option turned on, did that as I read it was a good idea, then before installing Linux and whipping out windows I unplugged like I always do and after installing ubuntu i plugged it and that message appeared. Im very afraid of losing data, as I tell you, that windows no longer exist and theres only ubuntu on my computer right now. What should I do? Will I lose all my data in order to use it on ubuntu? Or I have to plug it in a windows computer? I haven't plugged it to check it again and I'm really scared of data loss, it's more than 1 tb of valuable data.

Please help.

Comment: Did you try mounting the external disk read-only, like the error message suggests?  Your data is probably fine, but the ntfs file system needs repair (maybe from another Windows machine?).

Comment: As ubfan1 mentioned your data is safe in your HDD. Try connecting in a Windows machine and try.

Comment: Try connecting it to a windows machine, and then unmounting it with the "Safely remove drive" option before unplugging it, which should fix the problem. And, as always, you should always have two copies of your data (backups), in case something goes wrong, eg hardware failure.